# Remove Bing bar from Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, firefox, bing

Just launched Firefox this morning to find Microsoft has installed a huge Bing toolbar without asking me!?! They also changed my default search to Bing (as well as the context menu search on selected text) and attempted to change the home page. Same thing has happened in IE8.

Three things...

1. How do I uninstall them? (I can disable via FF extensions but not uninstall)
2. How do I restore the default search to Google (from address bar and right-click content menu on selected text?
3. WTF?

*Update:*
[According to Mozilla](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Removing+the+Search+Helper+Extension+and+Bing+Bar)...

> "Microsoft's latest Windows Update (KB982217) installs these [Search Helper Extension and Bing Bar] in Firefox for everyone who's previously used Windows Live Toolbar, MSN Toolbar, Windows Live Essentials or the Bing Bar."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How To Hide, Remove Or Uninstall Bing Bar From Firefox, Internet Explorer](http://www.dkszone.net/hide-remove-uninstall-bing-bar-firefox-internet-explorer)

> Want to remove Bing Bar from your system completely? Normally you can uninstall any Windows Live Essentials program by running the uninstaller from Control Panel –> Programs and Features. However in case of Bing Bar, you will not be able to find the option to remove it in the Uninstaller, which includes all other programs.
>
> Bing Bar is listed as a separate program in the Programs and Features control panel applet. Simply select it and click Uninstall to remove it.

Comment: I would have said that you got HiJacksers, but it's Microsoft.. so it doesn't make any sense.

(Download HijackThis and try to see if it catch something anyway)

Comment: Ta Matan. Still wondering about point no.3 though :¬)

Comment: My last comment was related to #3

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you get rid of it:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Go to Programs and Features
3. Look for Search and/or Conduit
4. Right click + uninstall it